# Oбособленное обстоятельство уступки?

Tags: синтаксис

*Он был готов начхать на все свои принципы и закрутить с ней любовь, **даже за деньги**, за звонкую золотую монету.*

Можно сказать, что выделенный фрагмент - это обособленное обстоятельство уступки?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

...даже за деньги, за звонкую золотую монету.

Это присоединительная конструкция, частица ДАЖЕ используется в качестве присоединительного союза "даже за деньги", далее следует уточнение "за звонкую золотую монету".

Можно дополнительно указать семантику конструкции: обстоятельство со значением уступки.